# Why are the 'Sun' shadows different to other light sources? Blender 2.8.1 Eevee

Tags: shadows

As you can see in the images below, the shadows cast from Sun are more accurate than ones cast from any other light type in Eevee. Why is this? Is there any way I can make a Point light cast shadows the same way as the sun, without enabling 'contact shadows'?

Here is the sun:

[image: Sun]

Here is the point:

[image: Point]

Comment: Hello :). By default both lights cast shadows correctly in Evee. Just tested it. Would you mind [sharing your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Hey there, the other comment by Richard Rude points out what I was after - The missing shadow on the base plate / narrow part of the doorknob.

Blend file is here, thanks.

Also, I'm aware contact shadows aren't turned on for the point, but I'd really like to know if the default accuracy of the sun light without 'contact shadows' on can be copied for a point, area, or spot light.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=0zK4ESwd" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/0zK4ESwd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the 'Bias' option for the non-sun light sources needed to be set to the absolute minimum. Everything looks great now.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know :). Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted later, so it's easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I imagine it could have something to do with the way the point lamp works.
I don't think that one is more accurate than the other but that the point lamp produces these perfectly harsh shadows because the light source, as the name suggests, comes from one single point and doesn't have any dimensions. If you think about it soft shadows can only occur when the edge receives more light than the center of the shadow. In case of the point lamp that isn't possible since all the light comes from the same point and thus casts exactly the same shadow.
I hope this makes sense. In my mind it does, at least

Edit: I just realized that you are talking about the missing shadow on the base plate of the door knob  In that case, I have absolutely no idea, sorry.

Edit 2: Do you have contact shadows turned on? Without contact shadows there tends to be a gap between the object and its shadow.

Comment: Your first edit points out what I was after!

I'm aware contact shadows aren't on, but I'm trying to find out if it's possible to get the sun's accuracy with any other light type, as it's the only light source that casts shadows correctly without needing to turn contact shadows on.Contact shadows 'work' for other light sources, but at a small price of inaccuracy.